# How to use the available C++17 flags from Xcode in Terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, c++17

My Xcode 9.2 has the option to compile C++ using: `-std=c++17` or `-std=gnu++17`.

My C++ code that has some C++17 features compiles successfully.

However, if I try to compile the same code in my Terminal using the same flags, I get the following errors:

`clang++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test
 error: invalid value 'c++17' in '-std=c++17'`

and

`clang++ -std=gnu++17 test.cpp -o test
 error: invalid value 'gnu++17' in '-std=gnu++17'`

My OSX version is 10.13.3 and my Clang++ version is:

`Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
 Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0`

I thought that Terminal would use the same compiler from Xcode. That may be the case, but I can't use the same options. At least I couldn't.

I tried using `-std=C++1z`, but it didn't compile my code because it doesn't understand some new features from C++17.

So my question is: Is there a way to use `-std=c++17` or `-std=gnu++17` that are currently available in my Xcode 9.2, in my Terminal app?

*This questions is not the same as the others available at stackoverflow because all the answers I found the `-std=c++17`options was not available in Xcode. Now we have this options, but I can't figure out how to use it in Terminal.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler Apple currently ships with Xcode 9.2 (`clang-900.0.39.2`) does not support the `-std=c++17` flag.

Xcode uses the `-std=c++1z` flag when you enable c++17 support. If you want to use `-std=c++17` you need to manually install clang. You could do that using `brew install llvm` (assuming you have homebrew installed).

You can compile your program with

`/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/bin/clang++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test`

You change the symlinks in `usr/bin/clang++` to point at the new destination if you don't want to use the full path to the compiler.

The compiler which is shipped with Xcode 9.3 will be

`Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.30)`

This can handle the `-std=c++17` flag.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if I go to the ```Building settings/Apple LLVM 9.0 - Language C++/C++ Language Dialect/``` and chose the option ```-std=c++17``` or ```-std=gnu++17``` Xcode is still using ```-std=c++1z``` to compile my code? If yes, why would they give my the c++17 and gnu++17 options if both at the end are the same c++1z? That's the part that is still unclear in my head.

Comment: The flags Xcode is actually using are `-std=c++1z` or respectively `-std=gnu++1z` you can see the exact compile command Xcode is using the Report Navigator. If you click on a build process on the left and enable "All Messages" you will see a line for each file Xcode is compiling. Open the details by clicking the lines icon on the right of the list entry. It will open up the exact build command used and also the warnings may appear in that file. The clang apple ships is just older than the `c++17` flag. During this time it was called `c++1z` since it was not clear if it will be 17 at the end.

Comment: Currently (Xcode version 12.4) Clang supports C++17. Goto Apple Clang - Language - C++, choose there C++ Language Dialect. If you don't see the C++17 option make sure your Clang compiler is up to date.